# Is my ROS properly installed?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just installed melodic on OSX and wonder if I've done it right as I've had to make a few changes. I've tried running `rosversion ros`, but I get `Cannot locate [ros]`. The command `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` inside `/opt/ros/melodic` gives no result. The command `roscore` gives the following:

> started roslaunch server
> http://mun-iMac.local:53241/ ros_comm
> version 1.14.3
>
> SUMMARY
>
> ========
>
> PARAMETERS  * /rosdistro: melodic  *
> /rosversion: 1.14.3
>
> NODES
>
> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid
> [11220]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://mun-iMac.local:11311/
>
> setting /run_id to
> fdde4302-c046-11e9-ae5e-b06ebf60167b
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid
> [11223] started core service [/rosout]

Does anyone know if it's properly installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330902/is-my-ros-properly-installed?/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why should it not be installed correctly? You can easily try to start a node, such as turtlesim and see if it works (rostopic echo /topicname -> to see if current data are in the topic)

---

Originally posted by [Horst](https://answers.ros.org/users/44887/horst/) with karma: 38 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on 2019-08-16**:
I've had to change quite a few things to get it running on OSX, so I wasn't quite sure. All good now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By looking at your roscore output, your ros is up and running and also you can see the version number in the parameters. For getting an output to rosversion, try checking the version of the basic ros packages. You can type rosversion roscpp.

---

Originally posted by [ksb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44805/ksb/) with karma: 36 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1